# GeoNetwork address format

Tags: metadata, address, geonetwork, format, europe

In GeoNetwork 3.4, the default format for Metadata information "Contact" is the American Format i.e. street, nummer, city, Postal Code, Country

example: `Rue Vautier 29, Bruxelles, 1000, Belgium`

However in Europe (in Belgium at least) it should be:

```
Rue Vautier 29, 1000 Bruxelles, Belgium
```

Otherwise the address is not valid. Do you know how to modify that?

The metadata files are harvested on a regular basis from a WAF so I can't (and don't want to) hard-code it.

Here is an example of a MD file

http://geonetwork.bmdc.be/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/metadata/bmdc.be:dataset:2023

Answer (score 1):

In the metadata itself its address is defined with its components separated individually, for example

```xml
<gmd:address>
  <gmd:CI_Address>
    <gmd:deliveryPoint>
      <gco:CharacterString>Rue Vautierstraat 29</gco:CharacterString>
    </gmd:deliveryPoint>
    <gmd:city>
      <gco:CharacterString>Brussel/Bruxelles</gco:CharacterString>
    </gmd:city>
    <gmd:postalCode>
      <gco:CharacterString>1000</gco:CharacterString>
    </gmd:postalCode>
    <gmd:country>
      <gmx:Anchor xlink:href="SDN:C32:7:BE">Belgium</gmx:Anchor>
    </gmd:country>
    <gmd:electronicMailAddress>
      <gco:CharacterString>bmdc@naturalsciences.be</gco:CharacterString>
    </gmd:electronicMailAddress>
  </gmd:CI_Address>
</gmd:address>
```

However, the record view uses the indexed value for `address` field. This is defined in this [XSLT file](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/blob/3.4.4/schemas/iso19139/src/main/plugin/iso19139/index-fields/language-default.xsl#L181-L183), like

```xml
        <xsl:variable name="address" select="string-join(../../../../gmd:contactInfo/*/gmd:address/*/(
                                      gmd:deliveryPoint|gmd:postalCode|gmd:city|
                                      gmd:administrativeArea|gmd:country)/gco:CharacterString/text(), ', ')"/>
```

It just joins `gmd:deliveryPoint`, `gmd:postalCode`, `gmd:city`, `gmd:administrativeArea` and `gmd:country` with a comma. In your example `Rue Vautier 29, Bruxelles, 1000, Belgium`.

One way to fix this could be to define individual variables for each component and then make the join in the order you want.

```xml
<xsl:variable name="deliveryPoint" select="../../../../gmd:contactInfo/*/gmd:address/*/
                                    gmd:deliveryPoint/gco:CharacterString/text()"/>
<xsl:variable name="postalCode" select="../../../../gmd:contactInfo/*/gmd:address/*/
                                      gmd:postalCode/gco:CharacterString/text()"/>
<xsl:variable name="city" select="../../../../gmd:contactInfo/*/gmd:address/*/
                                      gmd:city/gco:CharacterString/text()"/>
<xsl:variable name="administrativeArea" select="../../../../gmd:contactInfo/*/gmd:address/*/
                                      gmd:administrativeArea/gco:CharacterString/text()"/>
<xsl:variable name="country" select="../../../../gmd:contactInfo/*/gmd:address/*/
                                      gmd:country/gco:CharacterString/text()"/>




<xsl:variable name="address" select="string-join(($deliveryPoint, $postalCode, $city, $gmd:administrativeArea, $country)[. != ''],', ')"/>
```